# How would I delete these iptables rules?

Tags: iptables, delete

I added some rules blindly to iptables and now don't know how to remove them. It is the following:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6667 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.2
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport 6667 -d 192.168.4.2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.4.1
```

I don't know how these would look like under the `iptables -L` option, so I don't know which chain and number I should use. Can someone give me a slight hint as to what these would turn into under the -L output so I can delete them accordingly? Thanks so much!

Comment: Replace the -A in the above commands with -D. I am a bit surprised that you don't know which chain to use - the chains are FORWARD, PREROUTING and POSTROUTING. The command has a [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) that I recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sudo iptables -L
```

This command (above) will not show you all the rules you have just added. For example, the POSTROUTING chain will not be shown by this command. You should instead try the following command in addition:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L -n -v --line-number
```

To remove all four rules with ease, replace uppercase "A" (append) with uppercase "D" (delete)

```
$ sudo iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6667 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.2
$ sudo iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport 6667 -d 192.168.4.2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.4.1
```